# Rotating to a mirror pircture

Tags: image, xna, rotation

I loaded a picture to `texture2D` using `game.load.content<>()` ,I know I can rotate the picture
but is it possible to get their mirror pictures somehow?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spriteeffects.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `spriteBatch.Draw` method, use this:

```
sb.Draw(texture, position(Vector2), null, Color.White, rotation(float), Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally, 0f);
```

The last argument is the layerdepth (what "layer" the sprite is drawn on). The `SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally` flips the sprite as you requested. You can also mirror it verticlaly, than use `SpriteEffects.FlipVertically`. To rotate the sprite just edit the rotation part, it's a float, and it must be in Radians.